# Split string on a specific character if not preceded by a slash

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

Following a protocol document, I can receive an array of parameters encoded as an string in which each parameter is separated from others by a blank space. The spaces within parameters are escaped with backslashes.

So, let's say we have the following strings within a parameter array:

```
array('Eli is beautiful', 'Fran is ugly', 'Oso is nice')
```

These will be encoded in just one string as follows:

```
Eli\ is\ beautiful Fran\ is\ ugly Oso\ is\ nice
```

Encoding is not a major problem, but I am facing problems with decoding.

I try to split parameters using a regular expression, that should splits by spaces that are not after a backslash, so this is my code:

```
$params = preg_split('/[^\\\\]\s/', $str);
```

It splits the params as expected, but it also removes the last char for each one, so this is the output of var_dump:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(15) "Eli is beautifu"
  [1]=>
  string(11) "Fran is ugl"
  [2]=>
  string(11) "Oso is nice"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
$params = preg_split('/(?<!\\\\) /', $str);
```

The regex above matches every space that is not preceded by a backslash, which is exactly what you intend.

[**See it in action**](http://ideone.com/XK2Jj).

**Update:** Your previous regex eats up letters because it *matches* the character preceding the space (as long as it's not a backslash); therefore that character is considered part of the delimiter and removed from the output along with the space.

The lookbehind version *asserts* that no backslash precedes the space, but does not *match* the character -- an important difference.

Comment: I have detected a problem with this. When $str is void, it returns an array with one element containing 0... do you know why?

I will check for a void $str before applying the regex anyway...

Comment: @Fran: That's how all split-like functions work. If they find nothing to split on, they return one result: the original string itself. Since the original string is empty (same would happen if it were not a string but `null`) that's what you get back.